# how to add cors using aws sda v3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

im trying to update cors using aws sdk v3 but, i keep getting error `XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch`

here's detail the error

```
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 400,
    requestId: 'tx000000000000006119f03-00644b4bf3-2e418004-sgp1b',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Code: 'XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch',
}
```

my code is like this

```
const client = new S3Client({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    endpoint: `https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com`,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: key,
      secretAccessKey: key,
    },
  });
await s3Client().send(new PutBucketCorsCommand(params));
```

Comment: There is missing `\`` for the endpoint. Also, can you add what values does `params` variable hold?

Comment: sorry typo, but in my real code, im not missing the `quote`..